# Notify users when file has been uploaded

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I'm trying to use a Workflow to notify Azure AD Guest users when a file has been uploaded into the SharePoint Online folder that has been shared with them.  The alertme function isn't possible due to access restrictions.

I'm trying to use the Shared With (or Shared with details) fields on the Current Item Data Source to find the guest that needs an email.

I don't seem to be able to find a way to extract this information.  The Workflow History logs I create all indicate that the values are blank.  I know the folder (and thus file) are shared with external users.  I can't find anything on what these fields are or their format. Am I wrong on the data they'd contain?

Thanks.

Comment: what you mean by access restriction !

Comment: They have a custom permission on their own folder in the document library. They do not see the other 99 folders in the document library.  To create alerts, they'd need permissions on the top level folder, which we will not give them as they'd get alerts when a new folder (user) is added.  I don't want the headache of confused users. Hence workflows.